# How to use dimension x(n) in main program in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, dimensions

I want to make `x(1),x(2),x(3),...,x(n)` using dimension in Fortran.

Example :

```
n=10 
dimension x(n) 
do n=1,10
print*,x(n)
enddo
stop
end
```

But it's not allowed as far as I know...
And I get this error:

> symbol N is not permitted in a specification expression Errors in declarations, no further processing for main

How can I make `x(1),x(2),x(3),...,x(n)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to take a good text book to learn Fortran and look what the possibilities are in the Fortran language.

There are multiple ways e.g. using an allocatable:

```
integer, parameter :: n=10 
double precision :: x(:)
integer :: i
allocate(x(n))

do i=1,n
  x(i) = i
enddo

do i=1,n
  print*,x(i)
enddo

end
```

or using a fixed array:

```
integer, parameter :: n=10 
double precision :: x(n
integer :: i


do i=1,n
  x(i) = i
enddo

do i=1,n
  print*,x(i)
enddo

end
```